# PHP Memcache module is compiling with different module (debian)

Tags: php, debian, memcache

I've downloaded memcache-2.2.6 and when i run:

```
phpize && ./configure --enable-memcache && make
```

I get:

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
```

This is correct but after configure, make and adding the module to php.ini i get:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: memcache: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
```

Edit: The php its not from the debian package, its a manually php 5.3.8 install

Thanks

Comment: I assume from your tags this is debian.  Is there a reason you don't just `apt-get install php5-memcached`?  Are you not using php5 from the debian package?

Comment: No, its not from the debian package. I think i should specify that. Also i am using the phpize from the php folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like using pecl install memcache installed the correct memcache module version.

Answer (score 0):

why not just `apt-get install php5-memcache` or `apt-get install php5-memcached` (or both) depending on whether you need memcache or memcached and not bother with compiling?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use pecl, you can also specify the proper path to your php config in the ./configure command (use if you have multiple versions of php installed.)

```
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php53/bin/php-config
```